# How to disable the scrolling on OS X Safari?

Tags: safari, macos

What I would like to be able to do is set a certain part of a webpage in the viewport of Safari and then "Lock" the scrolling temporarily so that I can't accidentally scroll up or down and move what I have set up in that window.

Comment: Here's an idea: inject JavaScript to disable scrolling (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily) with Automator/Keyboard Maestro/AppleScript/etc?

Comment: this doesn't exactly solve your issue, but my guess is that there is something "counting" you want to keep track of, what you can do is right klick and then open in dashboard and thereof not worry about scrolling issues or refreshing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the post that [grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside) [linked to](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170021/how-to-disable-the-scrolling-on-os-x-safari#comment199807_170021), I've written a Safari/Chrome extension that adds a button to the context menu (right click) on every page, which allows you to "pause" scrolling, essentially locking the page in place. To unlock it, you just right click and choose "Resume Scrolling."

[image: Pause Scrolling]

You can download it [here](https://github.com/AstroCB/StopScroll-Extension).

Comment: Absolutely awesome extension!  do you have a firefox/chrome version in the works?

Comment: @Stape01 Not currently, but if you'd like one, I'd be happy to convert it to either (or both).

Comment: Both would be awesome if you could..

Comment: @Stape01 I've added Chrome support, and Firefox is on the way.